# Show a message when an area is non drag-droppable in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, drag-and-drop, tooltip, drag

I am new to angular and using angular drag and drop. I have "dnd-dragover" attribute in my container. Based on a boolean value from a method, the container will be toggled as draggable or non- draggable.

My questions/requirement:

1. In case of non-draggable scenario, we cannot drop elements into the container. I need to show an additional message saying "invalid attempt" additionally which will disappear after some time.
2. I tried uib-tooltip. It is not triggered on drag event.

I googled on it and couldn't find any feasible solution.Any help with the approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Better that you can provide us your code, otherwise I don't think we can help you